# QT check at least one row is selected QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I need a piece of code to check that the user has selected at least one row in a `QTableWidget`

The `QTableWidget` can be referenced using `ui->tableWidget`.

I'm trying to check there are selecting, if not, display a message box, if so, moving on to code I have written.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the selected rows from the selection model like:

```
QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = ui->tableWidget->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList *selectedRows = selectionModel->selectedRows();
if (selectedRows.size() > 0) {
    // There is at lease one selected row.
}
```

Comment: Spot on, I had the selected rows already, just wasn't sure what to put into the if statement. Appreciated :)